# Using browser Developer tool to Inspect the parameters sent when creating sharing links for our SharePoint documents. is this a correct way

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, share

I want to create/develop 2 SharePoint Rest API calls to share documents using :-

- Anyone link with Read-Only permission + Password
- "People you choose" link with Read-Only permission

now I did not find any official documentation from Microsoft regarding the parameters we can send using the ShareLink api endpoint.... So I went to SharePoint online UI and i inspected the parameters sent using the browser developer tool, as follow:-

- For the Anyone link with Read-Only permission + Password, i found that the following parameters will be sent:-

[image]

[image]

- for the "People you choose" link with Read-Only permission, I found the following parameters will be sent:-

[image]

[image]

Now since I did not find any official documentations about those parameters, so my question is, if I pass those parameters inside my code (.net code or Power Automate), will I always get the same result (now and in the future)? or for example, I might send the above parameters in the future and cause the sharing link to allow editing the document instead of Read-only? or those parameters should not be changed in the future by Microsoft? for example, currently "role:1" mean that the user will have Read-Only permission on the document been shared, so could the behavior of this parameter get changed in the future? so "role:1" grant the user edit instead of read-only?

Second question, in general why the ShareLink api end point does not have any official documentation mainly about the parameters options we have?

Regards